# What is the difference between C unions and C++ unions?

Tags: c++, c, unions

What are some major differences between unions in C and C++?

Comment: Please show the information you got and how it is "not useful".

Comment: This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 9):

In a nutshell, a C++ `union` can have constructors and destructors, and non-virtual functions. (Note that a C++ `union` cannot have a base class and cannot be a base class.)

Everything else is pretty much the same between C and C++.

Comment: IIRC there is no notion of "active member" in C, there is some non-trivial differences there. In particular, type-punning through a union in C++ is UB.